# ¿Por qué la suma de NAs me da cero?

Tags: r, rowsums, missings

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
set.seed(2)
va<-data.frame(x=rep(NA, 10),
               y=sample(c(NA,2,3),10,T))
va
    x  y
1  NA NA
2  NA  3
3  NA  2
4  NA  2
5  NA NA
6  NA NA
7  NA NA
8  NA NA
9  NA NA
10 NA  2
```

Y al sumar por columnas uso la función `rowSums()`.

```
rowSums(va[,1:2], na.rm = T)

[1] 0 3 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2
```

Pero obtengo que al sumar `NA` con `NA` me da cero. ¿`NA` con `NA` no debería ser `NA`?

¿A que se debe esto? ¿Hay otra función que al sumar dos o más columnas no me arroje cero como resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor `NA` tiene la característica que trasforma en NA cualquier suma independientemente del tipo de dato de su sumando:

```
> c(1 + NA, Inf + NA, NA + NA, 3i + NA)
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

En este sentido, las funciones como `rowSums()` y tantas otras tienen dos tratamientos con respecto a los `NA`, lo considera o los ignora (`na.rm = T`) y particularmente `rowSums()` [documenta el comportamiento](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.4-10/topics/rowSums) de tu ejemplo:

> If there are no values in a range to be summed over (after removing
> missing values with na.rm = TRUE), that component of the output is set
> to 0 (*Sums) or NaN (*Means), consistent with sum and mean.

Es decir, cuando los dos valores son `NA` el retorno será 0. Por lo que si lo que buscas es que en estos caso el valor sea `NA` habrá que hacer algo distinto:

```
apply(va, 1, function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

#### Adenda

El comportamiento de `rowSums()` guarda consistencia con el del simple `sum`, dónde `sum(NA,  na.rm=TRUE) == 0` y yendo más lejos `sum() == 0` y tiene que ver en cierta convención, aunque demostrable, para lo que se conoce como [suma vacía](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suma_vac%C3%ADa).

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, sí usando condicionales he resulto el problema, pero es muy curioso que el software arroje cero, debería de arrojar NA. No veo la conveniencia de arrojar cero.

Comment: Es el concepto de suma vacía, ahí agregue un poco más e información. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Con `na.rm = T` estás indicándole que ignore los `NA`. Si le indicas `na.rm = F` o no le indicas nada (por defecto esta inicializado a `FALSE`), te va a dar como resultado `NA`.

```
> set.seed(2)
> va<-data.frame(x=rep(NA, 10), y=sample(c(NA,2,3),10,T))
> rowSums(va[,1:2])
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Más información puedes verla en la documentación [aquí](https://search.r-project.org/R/refmans/base/html/colSums.html).

---

Añado el siguiente código por si quieres sumar en caso de que haya un `NA` en una columna y un número en otra.

```
> rowSums(va, na.rm=TRUE) *NA^!rowSums(!is.na(va))
[1] NA  3  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA  2
```

Comment: Sí, pero en este caso no se podría sumar las filas que sí contienen números. Ya que todo lo volvería NA.

Comment: Si los dos son números, te devuelve la suma de los dos números. Si hay un `NA`, te devuelve `NA`

Comment: Esta bien, pero se pierde la información de la columna que si tenía número. Por eso se usa estas funciones para poder sumar los que tienen NA con los que no.

Comment: En tu pregunte entendí que no preguntabas por eso, te añado una función por si te resulta de utilidad

Comment: Muchas gracias.